# BigQuery + Google Analytics: Calculating quantities purchased by SKU. UNNEST not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to calculate the total quantities purchased for individual SKU's between certain dates. Final output should be date / SKU / Qty_sold
My dataset is the Google Analytics sample public dataset.

**Main issue**: When I try to run the below query using item.itemQuantity, I get the below error:
Syntax error: Unexpected keyword UNNEST at [6:1]

If you see the screenshot for item.itemQuantity, it seems to be nested. By adding the UNNEST function, it's supposed to flatten the table and get the count. This is my understanding of UNNEST. However, when I apply UNNEST, the query doesn't run.

**Second issue**: When I check the BQ GA schema, the definitions for hits.item.itemQuantity and hits.product.productQuantity seem to be the same? and I'm unable to differentiate between the two fields and which one should I use in my query.
[https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTO2t.jpg)

hits.product.productQuantity    INTEGER The quantity of the product purchased.
hits.item.itemQuantity          INTEGER The quantity of the product sold.

Can anyone please explain how I can improve this query to get my desired result ? Thx.

```
SELECT
date, 
hits.item.productSKU AS SKU,
SUM(hits.item.itemQuantity) AS qty_sold
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` 
UNNEST (hits) hit
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX 
BETWEEN
'20160801' AND '20160802'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below for hits.product

```
SELECT
  date, 
  prod.productSKU AS SKU,
  SUM(prod.productQuantity) AS qty_purchased
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`, 
UNNEST (hits) hit, UNNEST(product) prod
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20160802'
GROUP BY date, SKU
```

or below for hits.item

```
SELECT
  date, 
  hit.item.productSKU AS SKU,
  SUM(hit.item.itemQuantity) AS qty_sold
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`, 
UNNEST (hits) hit
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20160802'
GROUP BY date, SKU
```

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. The first query executed. I'm guessing the UNNEST (product) had to be added as product type hits are different event type in GA and multiple products can be be passed in the same hit. Example: 2 products purchased in a single transaction. Clear on that. As a check, I tried checking on the SKU's in Google Analytics but the numbers don't match (or even the totals for BQ vs GA] . Example: SKU GGOEGGCX056299 shows 83 in BQ but only 10 in GA interface. This can be accessed via: https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/demoAccount . I have updated the screenshots for this error.